# How to inline sourcecode with doxygen

Tags: fortran, doxygen

I wanted to document a Fortran module containing functions with doxygen.

My problem is, that I can't find a way to include the body of my functions in the documentation of the functions. There is only a link to the position, but not the actual source code.

At the moment, my source code looks e.g. like this:

```
!> @brief      Get a starting time.
!> @details    Get an object with time information.
!> @return     returns the time with high precision
FUNCTION get_start_time() RESULT(stime)
  TYPE (time) :: stime

  CALL SYSTEM_CLOCK(stime%count, stime%rate, stime%max)
END FUNCTION
```

My doxygen configuration (the SOURCES part) looks like this:

```
SOURCE_BROWSER         = YES
INLINE_SOURCES         = YES
STRIP_CODE_COMMENTS    = YES
REFERENCED_BY_RELATION = YES
REFERENCES_RELATION    = YES
REFERENCES_LINK_SOURCE = YES
SOURCE_TOOLTIPS        = YES
USE_HTAGS              = NO
VERBATIM_HEADERS       = YES
```

I also tried to use the `@code` and `@endcode` flags to mark the source, but this doesn't work, too.

What should I do, to get the source code directly to the documentation?

---

**1st EDIT:** I tried @cheeseminer's solution. So the code above now looks like

```
!> @brief      Get a starting time.
!> @details    Get an object with time information.
!> @return     returns the time with high precision
!> @par        Code
!> @snippet    folder/file.F90 get_start_time
!! [get_start_time]
FUNCTION get_start_time() RESULT(stime)
  TYPE (time) :: stime

  CALL SYSTEM_CLOCK(stime%count, stime%rate, stime%max)
END FUNCTION
!! [get_start_time]
```

Unfortunately, the block-id commands (those with `!!` in front) appear in the documentation and/or the full source code. **What is the correct way, to do this in Fortran?**

**Or is there a better way to solve my initial question?**

---

**2nd EDIT:** I found a workaround which hides the block-id. I wrapped them in an `@internal` command.

```
!> @internal [get_start_time]
```

---

**3rd EDIT:** I'm now using @Michael's suggestion to include the block-id as HTML-Comment.

```
!> <!-- [get_start_time] -->
```

---

**4th EDIT:** I posted a follow-up [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21423690/2068635) concerning aliases.

Comment: I've not doxygenned Fortran myself, but looking at the manual don't you need to use `!>` for the snippet marker lines - at least, for the second one.  It does not seem to make sense to need the `@internal`.

Comment: Removing `@internal` and using `!>` to get `!> [get_start_time]`, I get the text "[get_start_time]" in the documentation (twice), which is not favourable. The `@internal` hides these occurrences.

Comment: Hmm, not favourable, I'd agree.  I'm afraid I'm out of suggestions now.

Comment: don't use `!>`... just use a normal comment, doxygen will still find it

Comment: @Michael You are right that Doxygen will find it. But this way, the comments appear in the full source code listing, because they are not stripped by the option `STRIP_CODE_COMMENTS`.

Comment: ah yes, I understand.  How about using HTML comments?  `!> <!-- [get_start_time] !>`

Answer (score 3):

I think what you are looking for is `@snippet`.  The relevant manual page is [here](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdsnippet).  You'll need to provide a path to the 'example' code in the doxyfile too.

`@code` is more of a formatting command.  If you have only a few short such sections you might be better to copy to code into the comment and use `@code` to format it, but if the code sample is liable to change then you probably should use `snippet` despite the clutter that it introduces into the source.

Comment: Thanks for this first approach. Unfortunately, I have some problems with the block markers, which still appear either in the full source code, or the documentation part...